# Arduino 3.5mm jack output

Tags: arduino, audio

I am trying to connect general speaker as an output to an Arduino Nano and play some tone.

My vision is:

- will connect:

  - Arduino D8 (digital) output pin to left and right channel
  - GND to GND
- in code, I will call [`tone(pin, frequency, duration)`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/tone/) function to play tone - `tone(8, 262, duration)` (`262` - C4 from [example](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/digital/toneMelody))

[image: Vision schema]

But in mentioned example, they use directly wired buzzer. **My question is, if this will work as is on image, and if is it save (I will not damage both speaker and Arduino).** I don't know, what voltage range is expected by speaker (on 3.5mm jack).

Comment: I need to make loud tone, not only silent beep. Thats why I need to connect bigger external speaker

Comment: what's a `general speaker`?

Comment: See https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/26101/4271

Comment: @jsotola `general speaker` - something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/Powered-3-5mm-Laptop-Speaker-Soundbar/dp/B00AOD7MYK)

Comment: @JYelton ohh, I tryed to google, but I haven't found this - thank you. But there are 2 answers that contradict each other - one says large is better, one small is better. But the capacitator that is mentioned in first comment is probab needed (I found it in another forum in different case), but I dont understand where any how :(

Comment: @Ondra that is an amplified speaker ... an arduino should be able to connect to that ... use a voltage divider at the arduino output  so that you don't overdrive the amplifier

Comment: @jsotola Yes, the speakers has own amplifier, so I dotn need so much power to play loud tone. I can put resistor between D8 and speaker and speaker pins - but how large?

Comment: I just found [this article](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/386930/connecting-an-arduino-to-desktop-speakers) - but saddly I dont knouw what to do